# Using Google Search REST API in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do a google search using Ruby, and print the 1st 3 results.

Could anyone point me to a sample code? I'm unable to find it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to select that. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gem [`googleajax`](http://github.com/geemus/googleajax) is there for that:

```
require 'googleajax'
GoogleAjax.referer = "your_domain_name_here.com"
GoogleAjax::Search.web("Hello world")[:results][0...3]
```

Comment: FYI: Google Web Search API is deprecated as of Nov 2010. It continues to work up, but results look strange to me and are very different from what the web UI is giving.

Comment: Example: `r = GoogleAjax::Search.web("Hello world")[:results][0]` then `puts r[:unescaped_url]`

Answer (score 3):

Now Google wants you to use this http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/ with a limit of 100 courtesy queries, and a pricing structure for anything above that.