# Ruby access/submit queries on websites

Tags: ruby, httpwebrequest

Say I wanted to create a ruby script that would access google, search for 'dogs', and then return the links of the top 5 results.  How would this be implemented in ruby?
Thanks.

*To clarify, I'm not looking for a way to search Google specifically.  I want this to work on other sites too, such as amazon.com, dictionary.com, etc.*

Comment: Please read: To clarify, I'm not looking for a way to search Google specifically. I want this to work on other sites too, such as amazon.com, dictionary.com, etc.

Comment: Writing a one-size-fits-all solution is not easy, because the different search engines use different parameters and their returned pages are completely different.

Comment: Right. So you'd essentially have to write the solution for each search provider you want to support, wrapped (most likely) in a main program that selected the appropriate solution based on some parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hack through it with hpricot, if a google api doesn't exist already.  Or here is a [script](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/826)

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to this question: [Using Google Search REST API in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676212/using-google-search-rest-api-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

I would use cURL to actually GET the page contents (its a simple GET request to google.com/?q=stuff). Then you'll need to use regular expressions and intuition to parse the DOM, extract the links, and display :)

Comment: Regular expressions would not be a good first choice for this. A HTML parser, like Nokogiri, is much more robust.